# Three .indexOf not match - return another result

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a redirect based on the OS in mobile devices.
I try to return the redirect in the following script

```
$(document).ready(function (){
//Android Version:
if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("android") != -1) {
window.location.href = "https://link1";
}
if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("iphone") != -1){
window.location.href = 'https://link2';
}

if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("ipad") != -1){
window.location.href = 'https://link3';
}
});
```

I need fourth redirect if none of the above true. But when I use at the end of the script:

```
 else {
window.location.href = 'https://link4';
}
```

Only ipad redirect works. Iphone and android redirects to link4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of the `if` statements needs an `else if` after it so that instead of 3 separate `if` statements, with the last one having an `else`, you have one `if` statement with multiple conditions.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  //Android Version:
  if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("android") != -1) {
    window.location.href = "https://link1";
  } else if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("iphone") != -1){
    window.location.href = 'https://link2';
  } else if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("ipad") != -1){
    window.location.href = 'https://link3';
  } else {
    window.location.href = 'https://link4';
  }
});
```

Comment: *"Best-Practice Evangelist (unless I'm in a lazy mood)"* <−−− brill-ee-ent :-D

Answer (score 1):

You need `else` on all of your subsequent `if`s. So:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    //Android Version:
    if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("android") != -1) {
        window.location.href = "https://link1";
    } else if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("iphone") != -1){
// ---^^^^
        window.location.href = 'https://link2';
    } else if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("ipad") != -1){
// ---^^^^
        window.location.href = 'https://link3';
    } else {
        window.location.href = 'https://link4';
    }
});
```

That way, if the first `if`'s condition is true, you only do what's in the `if` block. If the first `if`'s condition is false, you do the next `if`, and only do what's in *its* `if` block if it's true`. If none of the`if`conditions is true, you end up doing the`else` block at the end.

The above is the standard way to write it, but this verbose way may help make it clearer:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    //Android Version:
    if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("android") != -1) {
        window.location.href = "https://link1";
    } else {
        if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("iphone") != -1){
            window.location.href = 'https://link2';
        } else {
            if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("ipad") != -1){
                window.location.href = 'https://link3';
            } else {
                window.location.href = 'https://link4';
            }
        }
    }
});
```

That does exactly the same thing my first code block above does.